# Xamarin installation stuck at AndroidPlatform25

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to install xamarin to make my android App, a cross platform app. But the installation is stuck at "AndoridPlatform25" it's not the first I tried. Do you faced the same issue ?

[image]

In the same time I wanted to know if I got to change dependecies in my android project for C # libraries. Can I found equivalent to: Retrofit - Gson for exemple.

Comment: try using proxy or vpn

Comment: it's not a problem with the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xamarin installation stuck at AndroidPlatform25

You could refer to:

- [Unable to install androidplatform25](https://104.40.62.9/content/problem/171467/unable-to-install-androidplatform25.html)
- [PackageId:AndroidPlatform25;PackageAction:DownloadPackage;ReturnCode:0x80096004;](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/135245/packageidandroidplatform25packageactiondownloadpac.html)

> Can I found equivalent to: Retrofit - Gson for exemple.

If you need directly use `Retrofit/Gson` API in Xamarin, you could refer to: [Binding a Java Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/).

---

For `Gson`, you could refer to: [XamarinComponents - GoogleGson](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GoogleGson) and you could directly use it by adding a `nuget` reference.

For `Retrofit`, here is an automatic type-safe and async client for `REST`  library for `Xamarin` and `.NET`:

- [Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit) is a library heavily inspired by Square's Retrofit library

Comment: Thx, for my installation problem it was due to my antiviru. I disabled it.

Comment: But It's like i don't have the entire xamarin software. Because when I want to follow a tutorial I see I don't have the same project structure, I can't create .xaml file... do I have to start over the installation.